# Unable to commit via Subclipse+SVNKit due to no valid credentials

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnkit, javahl

I recently upgraded several packages on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, and now Subclipse is unable to commit, giving me the error:

```
svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
```

This is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904216/subversive-reject-credentials) to a problem I had with Subversion, but I believe due to a different cause.

Prior to the upgrade, I was using Subclipse with the JavaHL adapter, which worked just fine. After the upgrade, Eclipse complained:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I then used Eclipse's updater to upgrade Subclipse itself to the most recent 1.10 and reinstall the JavaHL component, but that failed to solve the problem. However, it did allow me to install the SVNKit component, which I did, and switched to via Team->SVN. That solved the "Failed to load JavaHL Library." error, but just replaced it with the "No valid credentials" error.

I've confirmed the credentials I'm using a still valid, and I can login to the serve with them. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To use JavaHL with Subclipse 1.10.x, you will need Subversion 1.8.x binaries installed.  That is probably your best option.  See:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

The error mentions "Negotiate", which I think is Kerberos.  Perhaps SVNKit does not support it, or needs something to be configured.  I would email support@svnkit.com with details. They are pretty responsive and it is possible that SVNKit can support this

Comment: You're probably right, in that I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, so the libsvn-java package version is 1.6, which is probably subtly breaking everything. The server uses Kerberos behind the scenes, but I still have to login with username/password, so that shouldn't be an issue. My client machine does not use Kerberos.